# Remote validation with additionalfields >> one more POST?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery

I have an ASP.NET MVC3 solution. I use remote validation for checking whether a username already exists.

At a first stage, I user the following validation attribute:

```
[Required, Remote("UserNameAlreadyExists", "User", Error="Already exists!"]
public string UserName { get; set; }
```

Here is the trace at runtime:

[image]

Then I realised I need to pass additional field (userID) to validate thus I do:

```
[Required, Remote("UserNameAlreadyExists", "User", AdditionalFields="UserID", Error="Already exists!"]
public string UserName { get; set; }
```

Here is the trace at runtime:

[image]

You'll see that there is one more POST ?!

Why? Tt is a problem in my situation. This drives me crazy.

Thanks for your help.

---

UPDATE

Here is the code of my Edit.cshtml

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.UserID)

    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.UserName)                     
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.UserName)
    ...
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
}
```

Here is the javascript code

```
    $('form', dialog).submit(function () {
        // Do not submit if the form does
        // not pass client side validation
        if (!$(this).valid()) {
            writeError("Validation failed!");
            return false;
        }

        // On the line below: I retrieve the POST url + serialize all submitted data from my form
        $.post($(this).attr('action'), $(this).serialize(), function (data, status) {
              ...
              ...
        }).error(function (error, status, a, b) {
            alert('Error!');
        });
        // Unbind form submitting
        $('form', dialog).unbind();
        return false;
    });
```

When I debug my code (step by step) I can note some points:

- the form is submitted and intercepted by my jquery function
- the UserAlreadyExists is triggered (why?). In this function (on the second line) I have: var user = _requestServiceClient.GetUserFromUserName(userName); WHEN step on this line, I suddently step into post action of Edit. Strange!? Some step later, it step back in the function UserAlreadyExists. Still strange!?

I don't know if the problem is in my code or if my version of jquery.validate.min.js is outdated and bugged or something else...

I noticed that if I don't use any AdditionalFields, I don't have any problems!!

I also noticed that if I trigger the UserAlreadyExists volontary (by focus in the field) I don't have any problems when submitting (posting)!!

**So I have problems when the form Edit is showed and UserName field is not focused! Then I submit and problems arrived**

Thanks.

Comment: Can you show your view code especially how do you post your form?

Comment: @nemesv: I updated my question to show some code and additional information.